# Build path and use in external command

Tags: vbscript

How to insert my `SCRIPT_PATH` Variable into PowerShell script path? Also anyone know any Visual Studio Like tool I can write those? I think Visual Studio uses different .net vbs.

Here is the code:

```
SCRIPT_PATH = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, Len(WScript.ScriptFullName) - (Len(WScript.ScriptName)))
MsgBox SCRIPT_PATH
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "RUNAS  /user:Domain\User ""powershell SCRIPT_PATH & Delete_App_Script.ps1"""
Set objShell = Nothing
```

How do I do `SCRIPT_PATH = SCRIPT_PATH + Delete_App_Script.ps1`?
`SCRIPT_PATH = SCRIPT_PATH & "Delete_App_Script.ps1"` doesn't work.
It gives no errors, so I am not sure what is the problem.
Am I missing some `""` or some `,,`?

I've seen some `.Run ,,,` syntax for Admin running and this one, doesn't explain what goes into `""`.
Not looking forward creating interface for this.

This doesn't work:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
SCRIPT_PATH = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, Len(WScript.ScriptFullName) - (Len(WScript.ScriptName)))
SCRIPT_PATH = SCRIPT_PATH & "Delete_App_Script.ps1"    
objShell.Run "RUNAS  /user:Dom\adm ""powershell SCRIPT_PATH"""
Set objShell = Nothing
```

But this works:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "RUNAS  /user:Dom\adm ""powershell C:\Delete_App_Script.ps1"""
Set objShell = Nothing
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You have to concatenate the variable `SCRIPT_PATH` to the string. Something like `objShell.Run "RUNAS  /user:Dom\adm ""powershell " &  SCRIPT_PATH & """"`.

Comment: Thank you it worked. Good to know for the future.

Comment: as for an IDE, consider VBSEdit.

Comment: Thanks, it's going much faster now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the appropriate [`FileSystemObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) methods when handling paths:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

SCRIPT_PATH = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
SCRIPT_PATH = fso.BuildPath(SCRIPT_PATH, "Delete_App_Script.ps1")
```

For using variables inside strings you need to concatenate the variables to the rest of the string, as [@Lankymart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247163/variable-path-in-vb-script#comment63917787_38247163) pointed out. This is also documented in the [language tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info).

```
objShell.Run "RUNAS /user:Domain\User ""powershell " & SCRIPT_PATH & """"
```

Note also that you should put the path in double quotes in case it contains spaces:

```
objShell.Run "RUNAS /user:Domain\User ""powershell \""" & SCRIPT_PATH & "\"""""
```

and you should use the parameter `-File`, otherwise PowerShell would interpret the script path as a command string, which wouldn't fail for paths with spaces.

```
objShell.Run "RUNAS /user:Domain\User ""powershell -File \""" & SCRIPT_PATH & "\"""""
```

Comment: You have a space after `/user:` and an asterisk in the concatenation (`a &*"`). Both shouldn't be there.

Comment: It was extra space after "/user" the * I was trying to do bold )).
Thanks

Comment: Hello, how do I run it silently? adding `,0` to `SCRIPT_PATH & "\""""", 0` doesn't work. I apologize for what could be a dumb question, this syntax is very unfamiliar to me.

Comment: You can't run it silently since you want to switch the user context.

Comment: even if I do something like this?
`objShell.Run "RUNAS  /user:ONE\" & User & " ""powershell -File \""" & SCRIPT_PATH & "\""""",0
WScript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys Pass 'send password 
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Set objShell = Nothing`

Comment: No. Plus, you don't ever want to do that in the first place.