# Get path from VBscript variable to use with obj.sql(extQuery) extQuery = select * from table name into outfile '????'

Tags: mysql, vbscript, into-outfile

I have this code i need to retrieve a path from a VBScript variable and use it with a mysql query.

```
set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Mypath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
Fullpath = fso.buildpath(Mypath,"test.txt")
```

then later in the code i need to launch a query with:

```
obj.sql(extQuery)

extQuery = "select * from table_name into outfile '?????'.....
```

What do i need to do to get the path from my variable and use it in the query ?
Hope someone could show me an example.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use string concatiantion

```
obj.sql(extQuery)

extQuery = "select * from table_name into outfile '" & Fullpath  &  "'....


extQuery = "SELECT *  INTO OUTFILE '" & Fullpath   & "'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM table_name ;".
```

You have also to add

```
 Fullpath = Replace(Fullpath , "\", "/")
```

As the `\`is an escape parameter in mysql

Comment: Thanks @nbk, i got error22 message sql can't write/create file invalid argument, is that a syntax mistake ?

Comment: your synstax maybe wrong, i added an example. if you have problems, print the extQuery  variable, so that i can check it

Comment: I see in the error message mysql returned a problem with the path: example: C:UsersUserDocuments, there are no backslash \ in the path

Comment: As you see in this thread it should work https://stackoverflow.com/a/38283050/5193536

Comment: please try `Fullpath = Replace(Fullpath , "\", "\\") ` and if that doesn't help `Fullpath = Replace(Fullpath , "\", "/") both should work wioth mysql

Comment: The correct one , "\", "/" @nbk !!!